# v-autocomplete how to detect if no result and add custom action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify which searches a list of users. If there are no results I want to show a second button that allows you to create a new user:

```
    <v-autocomplete
            v-model="event.user"
            :items="usersData"
            label="Seach speaker list"
            :search-input.sync="searchUser"
            return-object
            item-value="id"
            item-text="name"
          >
          </v-autocomplete>
```

This is the button to show. How to I conditionally allow this if there are no results?

```
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="8">
        <v-row>
          <v-subheader>
            Can’t find who you’re looking for?
          </v-subheader>
        </v-row>

        <v-btn>
          <v-icon>
            mdi-plus
          </v-icon>
          Add new speaker
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `v-if` directive in `v-row`. I assume that `usersData` is an array:

```
<v-row v-if="usersData.length == 0">
  <v-col cols="8">
    <v-row>
      <v-subheader>
        Can’t find who you’re looking for?
      </v-subheader>
    </v-row>

    <v-btn>
      <v-icon>
        mdi-plus
      </v-icon>
      Add new speaker
    </v-btn>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```